# Lebesgue integral of non-negative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Assume that $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a Lebesgue measureable function such that $f(x) > 0$ for a.e $x.$. Show that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $\delta >0$ such that for every Lebesgue measurable set $E$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda(E) \geq \epsilon$ we have $\int_{E} f d \lambda \geq \delta$.

An idea: We proceed by contradiction: Suppose there exists an $\epsilon_{0}$ and a sequence of measurable sets $\{E_{n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that for all n, we have $\lambda (E_{n}) \geq \epsilon_{0}$ while $2^{-n} > \int_{E_{n}}f d\lambda$.
For each $n$, define $F_{n} = \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}E_{k}$, which is a decreasing sequence of sets. $F = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup E_{n}$.

By the continuity of $\lambda$ from above, we have $\lambda (F) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \lambda(E_{n}) \geq \epsilon_{0}$.

I do not see how this leads to a contradiction. Perhaps there is a better way. I will appreciate a hint or a solution.

Comment: You have not used the fact: $f>0$ a.e. Therefore, it is impossible to construction a contradiction.

Comment: Imagine the extreme case that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, and in the above $E_n=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $1>\epsilon>0$ and $F_R = \{x\in [0,1] : 0 < f(x) \le R\}$. Let $c >0$ be given by
$$c = \inf \{ R>0: \lambda (F_R) \ge \epsilon\}.$$
As $f(x) >0$ a.e., we have $c >0$. 
$$\bigcap_{R \ge c} F_R = F_c,$$
we have $\lambda (F_c) \ge \epsilon$ and $\lambda(F_d) <\epsilon$ for all $d <c$. Write 
$$F_c = \{f(x) = c\} \cup \{f(x) < c\}.$$
Note that $\lambda(\{f(x) < c\}) \le \epsilon$. Let $D$ be such that 
$$ \{ f(x) < c\} \subset D \subset \{ f(x) \le c\} = F_c\ \ \ \text{and } \lambda (D) = \epsilon.$$
Let $\delta = \int_{D} f d\lambda >0$. Let $E$ be any measurable set in $[0,1]$ and $\lambda (E)\ge \epsilon$. Then

$$\begin{split} \int_E f d\lambda &= \int_{E\cap D} f d\lambda + \int_{E\setminus D} fd\lambda \\
&\ge \int_{E\cap D} f d\lambda + \int_{E\setminus D} c d\lambda \\
&= \int_{E\cap D} f d\lambda + \lambda(E\setminus D)c 
\end{split}$$
As 
$$\begin{split}\lambda (E\setminus D) + \lambda (E\cap D) &= \lambda (E) \\
&\ge \epsilon \\
&= \lambda (D) \\
&= \lambda (D\cap E) +\lambda (D\setminus E)\\
\Rightarrow \lambda (E\setminus D) &\ge \lambda (D\setminus E) .
\end{split}$$
So 
$$\begin{split} \int_E fd\lambda &\ge  \int_{E\cap D} f d\lambda + \lambda(D\setminus E)c\\
&=  \int_{E\cap D} f d\lambda + \int_{D\setminus E} cd\lambda \\
&\ge \int_{E\cap D} f d\lambda + \int_{D\setminus E} fd\lambda \\
&= \int_D fd\lambda = \delta .
\end{split}$$

Comment: There are many gaps in the proof:

1. Why the set $\left\{ R>0\mid\lambda(F_{R})\geq\epsilon\right\} $
is non-empty? (Although it is correct, it needs a proof.)

2. The fact that $\lambda(F_{c})\geq\epsilon$ also needs a proof.
(You need to point out that for each $R>c$, $\lambda(F_{R})\geq\epsilon$.
Also, $\cap_{R\geq c}F_{R}=F_{c}$ does not help because $F_{c}$
is already included in LHS. This line should be modified to something
like $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{c+\frac{1}{n}}=F_{c}$.)

Comment: 3. The existence of the set $D$ needs a proof. Denote $A=\{x\mid f(x)<c\}$
and $B=\{x\mid f(x)\leq c\}$. We have arrived a step that $A\subseteq B$,
$\lambda(A)\leq\epsilon$ and $\lambda(B)\geq\epsilon$. It is not
clear why we can find a set $D$ with $A\subseteq D\subseteq B$ such
that $\lambda(D)=\epsilon$. (For example, if $\lambda$ is replaced
with counting measure, $\epsilon=0.5$, $A=\emptyset$, $B$=singleton.
Then $A\subseteq B$ and $\lambda(A)\leq\epsilon$, $\lambda(B)\geq\epsilon$.
Obviously, we cannot find a set $D$ with $A\subseteq D\subseteq B$
and $\lambda(D)=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_{n}=\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x)\geq\frac{1}{n}\}$.
Then $A_{1}\subseteq A_{2}\subseteq\ldots$ and $\cup_{n}A_{n}=\{x\mid f(x)>0\}$
which has measure 1.
Denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ by $\lambda$. We have $1=\lambda(\cup_{n}A_{n})=\lim_{n}\lambda(A_{n})$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $n$ such that $\lambda(A_{n}^{c})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. (Here, the complement is relative to the set $[0,1]$.)
Let $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$. Let $E\subseteq[0,1]$ be a measurable set
with $\lambda(E)\geq\varepsilon$. Observe that 
$$
\lambda(E\cap A_{n})=\lambda(E)-\lambda(E\cap A_{n}^{c})\geq\varepsilon-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
and $f\geq\frac{1}{n}$ on $A_{n}\cap E$. Therefore, 
$$
\int_{E}f\,d\lambda\geq\int_{E\cap A_{n}}f\,d\lambda\geq\frac{1}{n}\lambda(E\cap A_{n})\geq\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\delta.
$$